# html form on reloading page is not cleared on form send

Tags: php, html, forms, post, put

I am working on a website that has a kind of questionare. It is a PHP script that reads the questions from a database and shows some content depending on your answers. The user will click an answer and the page will reload re-posting the previously entered form data so the already answered questions will show disabled buttons/radio forms with the answers checked.

I noticed during debugging that the previously sent stuff is not cleared and always reposted (the page works however, i just thought it looks unclean)

example:
?position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1&p_item9=2&position=9&p_item1=4&p_item2=2&p_item3=4&p_item4=2&p_item5=2&p_item6=2&p_item7=2&p_item8=1#lastrow

how can i get rid of the post/put data getting exponentially bigger?

Comment: Use sessions and post

Comment: i normally use post I was just using get/put for debugging reasons. So I can just ignore these symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the "answer" you are referring to is a link. If so, you can easily use the $_POST superglobal to send the data:

```
<!-- javascript that creates the post() function-->
<script>
    function post(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
</script>

<!-- form with the information you want to post-->
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="my_form" style="display: none;">
<?php 
    /*You'll have to create the needed php code that will echo the
    hidden inputs for the form that should look like this:
        <input type="hidden" name="position" value="9" />
        <input type="hidden" name="p_item1" value="4" />
        ... and so on.*/
    ?>    
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="post()">Your Link</a>
```

Comment: No the answer is a form radio "onchange" element and the previously answered questions are beeing reposted by 

    for ( $counter = 1 ; $counter < $position ; $counter++ ) { if ( ${'p_item'.$counter} != "" ) { print ("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p_item$counter\" value=\"${'p_item'.$counter}\">\n"); } }

however it re-sends the previously posted items again